# sendmail cron job successfully sends out emails, but emails are not reaching my inbox

Tags: linux, cron

I created a script /etc/cron.hourly/test-hourly to send an email to me:

```
#!/bin/bash

EMAIL_TO="example@example.com"
EMAIL_CC="example@example.com"
SUBJECT="Cron hourly test $(date)"
BODY="Cron hourly test $(date)"

echo "Cron hourly test $(date)"
{
        echo "To: $EMAIL_TO"
        echo "Cc: $EMAIL_CC"
        echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
        echo ""
        echo "$BODY"
} | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

I can verify that the cron job is being executed successfully, as I can see the following log messages under /var/log/cron

```
May 23 12:01:01 hostname CROND[26928]: (root) CMDOUT (/etc/cron.hourly/test-hourly:)
May 23 12:01:01 hostname CROND[26928]: (root) CMDOUT ()
May 23 12:01:01 hostname CROND[26928]: (root) CMDOUT (Cron hourly test Tue May 23 12:01:01 MST 2023)
```

The job seems to also have no problems with sending out the mail, but for some reason, my inbox never receives the mail. The following are the entries in the /var/log/maillog

```
May 23 12:01:01 hostname sendmail[26947]: 34NJ11jc026947: from=root, size=156, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202305231901.34NJ11jc026947@hostname.localdomain>, relay=root@localhost
May 23 12:01:01 hostname sendmail[26948]: 34NJ11ks026948: from=<root@hostname.localdomain>, size=431, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202305231901.34NJ11jc026947@hostname.localdomain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
May 23 12:01:01 hostname sendmail[26947]: 34NJ11jc026947: to=example@example.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30156, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (34NJ11ks026948 Message accepted for delivery)
May 23 12:01:02 hostname sendmail[26951]: 34NJ11ks026948: to=<example@example.com>, ctladdr=<root@hostname.localdomain> (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=120431, relay=example.example.com. [x.x.x.x], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent ( <202305231901.34NJ11jc026947@hostname.localdomain> Queued mail for delivery)
```

I tested sendmail on its own, and I can receive the email on my inbox:

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v example@example.com
```

Is there anything I am missing on why the mails from the cron hourly job is not reaching my inbox? I have checked the spam and trash folders as well just in case, but nothing.

**UPDATE**
I added log files from when I manually ran sendmail from the command line.

Here is what the maillog logs look like after I manually ran sendmail and successfully received the mail on my inbox

```
May 23 12:42:56 hostname sendmail[31309]: 34NJgu7J031309: from=admin, size=23, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202305231942.34
NJgu7J031309@hostname.localdomain>, relay=admin@localhost
May 23 12:42:56 hostname sendmail[31310]: 34NJguoT031310: from=<admin@hostname.localdomain>, size=336, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202305231942.34NJgu7J031309@hostname.localdomain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
May 23 12:42:56 hostname sendmail[31309]: 34NJgu7J031309: to=example@example.com, ctladdr=admin (1001/1001), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30023, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (34NJguoT031310 Message accepted for delivery)
May 23 12:42:57 MWQ1ZWEB4 sendmail[31312]: 34NJguoT031310: to=<example@example.com>, ctladdr=<admin@hostname.localdomain> (1001/1001), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=120336, relay=hostname.hostname.com. [x.x.x.x], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent ( <202305231942.34NJgu7J031309@hostname.localdomain> Queued mail for delivery)
```

The difference between the two are the **from** fields are root in the cron job's instance, and admin (the user account I used) for the manual run. What do I need to configure to make this work properly?

Comment: As a first step, can you add/compare the logs for this to the entries in the `/var/log/maillog` for your manual `sendmail` email?

Comment: I edited the post and added the log entry for when I manually ran sendmail. It looks like the sendmail from the script has root for the from field, while the manual method has admin as the from field

Comment: Can you try running the cron job as admin (not as root)? (`sudo crontab -u admin -e`) That way you can see if it's simply an issue with mail sent from root.